# Why can't I play songs downloaded on iOS 7?

Tags: itunes, music

I downloaded songs on my iPhone 5 with iOS 7 and the songs played fine yesterday. When I connected to iTunes, the songs became unavailable on my iPhone with a red square and red circle around the square. The songs also do not appear in iTunes. Please help??

Comment: I assume you are syncing them through iTunes and are trying to play them in the Music app on the phone. Can you add a link to a screenshot showing the problem?

Answer (score 1):

You should check iTunes->Preferences

- Automatic Downloads
- iTunes in the Cloud Preferences

If nothing helps and if these songs are not listed in your iTunes Store->Purchased history you have to contact apple...

Answer (score 1):

all you have to do is connect your phone to the computer, open itunes. go into your phone on the left hand side, and go all the way to the bottom to options and check the "sync only checked songs and videos" box. it worked straight away for me, hope this helped you

Answer (score 1):

This means your iPhone library file got corrupted. Just add one or two songs from your computer to your iPhone via iTunes and iTunes sync should fix the file.